# Creating a JSON by filtering from an existing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mapreduce

I am trying to create a JSON by filtering from the parent JSON by filtering the parent node name and the a few child nodes inside it . While doing it I get the following error

`Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at data.children.filter.map.Object.assign.children.o.children.reduce`

https://jsfiddle.net/snt1/nLua0oob/13/

Comment: Kind of a guess, but on line 1305, did you mean `o.children.filter` instead of `a.children.fiter`? Based on the data, at that point, `a` has `name`, `code`, and `count`, but no `children`. However, `o` *does* have `children`

Comment: the error seems simpler than that `TypeError: a.children is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
result = data.children
    .filter(o => o.name === 'Age')
    .map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        {
            children: o.children.filter(o => o.name === 'Male' || o.name === 'Female')
        }
    ));

console.log(result);
```

I could only find one instance each of the strings `"Male"` and `"Female"`  in your data and this pulls them out.

Comment: Could you also let me know if I could read more on this from any documentation to get the idea about it map reduce filter. Thank You

Comment: They are all methods of the `Array` class, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array